# make .content and .footer height 100%

Tags: php, css, html, wordpress

Hello I need help setting the `.content` and `.footer` to stick to the bottom of the page.

I did a WordPress template.

[my website](http://bravocreations.com/wp/)

you can see the black line is not all the way at the bottom. I add CSS to the `.footer`

```
clear: both;   
position:fixed;   
right:0px;   
left:0px;   
bottom:0px;
```

which did the trick but only to the footer. the `.content` which is the center screen in cut off. the only way to bring it down is by setting the min height to a higher number. please help

Thanks You

Comment: Maybe http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/keeping-footers-at-the-bottom-of-the-page

Comment: Please include the relevant HTML in your question, preferably as a runnable snippet that shows the problem.

Comment: What is the relevance of php tag, html5 tag and wordpress tag for the question?

Answer (score 0):

You can do the same thing to the content class:

```
.content{
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
}
```

Keep in mind, the moment you do this, the content div will disappear since you have nothing in it. In this case, just add a min-width.

Comment: i did that and nothing happend

Comment: @user1727251 I did it with no problem, here's a picture: http://gyazo.com/53ffce5ca66ff32b6ff4a52eebb4c496

Comment: actually now the top of the content is missing . what i mean is it switched to the top

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Would you like the grey to take up the entire height of the page?

Comment: yes the the backgound go from the header to the footer on all the center content

Comment: Any one esle has an idea ?

Comment: Seems like you got it. I was out for the day